# Vue computed properties, issues with addition vs concatenation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, computed-properties

Just learning Vue and I stumbled upon an interesting behavior, I'd like to know why this happens and how to avoid it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="number" v-model="a" style="color: white" />
    <input type="number" v-model="b" style="color: white" />
    <p style="color: white">{{ c }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
  },
  computed: {
    c: function() {
      return this.a + this.b;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

On first render, 'c' is displayed as '3', which is what I would expect.  If I change one of the inputs, however, the two numbers are concatenated.  For example if I changed 'a' to '11', my expected value would be 13, but I'm getting '112'.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Number` object constructor in order to make the sum :

```
  computed: {
    c: function() {
      return Number(this.a) + Number(this.b);
    }
  }
```

the two operands are considered as strings which will be concatenated when you try to put `+` between them, in order to avoid that default behavior try to use `Number` constructor or `parseInt`, `parseFloat` function to change the behavior to sum operation.

or try to use `number` modifier in `v-model` directive like :

```
<input type="number" v-model.number="b" style="color: white" />
```

Comment: That works. I don't fully understand why it's necessary though.  Maybe it will become more clear as I work through the docs.  
Edit - What really confuses me is why it renders 3, and not 12, at first and then switches to concatenation on input...

Comment: i think the `number` modifier is the best solution since we are working with vue

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know why Vue initially calculates "3" instead of "12"? Maybe it doesn't matter, since you've provided a few work-arounds, but I don't have a particular use case at the moment, I'm just trying to learn the framework.

Comment: the data initially declared and cast as numbers `1` but when you type the data will be updated as strings `'1'`

Comment: Yes! Just found it in the docs...


_"v-model will ignore the initial value, checked, or selected attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component."_


Therefore... the initial data is a number, the input field is being interpreted as a string, even though it is set to type="number". Vue obviously doesn't look at that and so your v-model.number would be the most correct way to approach this. Feels good learning new stuff lol.